# Res.redirect does nothing in my angular-express

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

Here is what I building.

[1. Node/Express Server](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/5406)

[2. Angular Routes](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/5403)

[3. Database functions](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/5404)

[4. Controllers](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/5405)

So this function in my 1st file

```
function requireUser(req, res, next){
  if (!req.user) {
    res.redirect('/user/register');
  } else {
  next();
 }
}
```

when I comment out the redirect line, nothing happens, but otherwise it just goes to my main page.

[image: log]

Also, no matter I change the redirect to, it still does nothing.

```
GET /user/NOTHING 304 32.466 ms - -
GET /api/posts 304 7.082 ms -
```

no error at all, just tries the GET, and somehow can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to choose other way, if user isn't authorized you can return response with 401 status code (this status code means "Unauthorized request")
and after that your angular.js application should handle this response and redirect user to register page. I mean your backend can't redirect user to another page of your frontend app. it can just say: hey you are not authorized! and only your frontend app can redirect user to register page